# Official bzip2 site is offline

Tags: bzip2

Recently, I found out, that the official bzip page has changed (http://www.bzip.org/index.html). I had a script, which took the source code from bzip.org and compiled it. Now, the source code and all other stuff are not anymore on this site.

I found, that there is a possible copy of that code at https://github.com/enthought/bzip2-1.0.6.

But I am unsure, if this is the real bzip2 code without any harmful changes. Is there another official bzip.org site or another site, where I can download the official source code?

Comment: looks off-topic to me

Answer (score 4):

You may still access the source from web archives
https://web.archive.org/web/20180624184806/http://www.bzip.org/downloads.html